# Spring value injection in mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, mockito

I'm trying to write test class for the following method

```
public class CustomServiceImpl implements CustomService {
    @Value("#{myProp['custom.url']}")
    private String url;
    @Autowire
    private DataService dataService;
```

I'm using the injected url value in one of the methods in the class.
To test this i've written a junit class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-test.xml" })
public CustomServiceTest{
    private CustomService customService;
    @Mock
    private DataService dataService;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        customService = new CustomServiceImpl();
        Setter.set(customService, "dataService", dataService);
    }    
    ...
}

public class Setter {
    public static void set(Object obj, String fieldName, Object value) throws Exception {
        Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(obj, value);
    }
}
```

In applicationContext-test.xml I'm loading the property file using

```
    <util:properties id="myProp" location="myProp.properties"/>
```

But the url value is not getting loaded in the CustomService on running the test.
I was wondering if there is anyway to get this done.

Thanks

Comment: If you're mocking `CustomService`, then how is `CustomServiceImpl` being used?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm using CustomeServiceImpl. Updated the code. How can I mock the value of url which needs to be read from the properties file?

Comment: As it now stands, you are not using Spring to set the customService value, you setting the value manually in the setup() method with this code: `customService = new CustomServiceImpl();`

Comment: No i'm not using spring to set the customService value for tests but in the actual application i'm using spring to set the value. Is it possible to mock the value of url like i'm doing it for dataService?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can autowire into a mutator (setter), rather than just annotating the private field. Then you can use that setter from your test class as well. No need to make it public, package private will do as Spring can still access it, but otherwise only your test can get in there (or other code in the same package).

```
@Value("#{myProp['custom.url']}")
String setUrl( final String url ) {
    this.url  = url;
}
```

I'm not a fan of autowiring differently (compared to my codebase) just for testing, but the alternative of changing the class under test, from the test, is simply unholy.

Comment: do you know if this also works with the `@Resource` annotation ?

Answer (score 66):

```
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public CustomServiceTest{

@InjectMocks
private CustomServiceImpl customService;

@Mock
private DataService dataService;

@Before
public void setup() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(customService, "url", "http://someurl");
}    
...
}
```

Comment: Could you also explain your solution with a few words?

Comment: The question from Rohit might have other issues, but while searching for a solution to my problem, this solution was exactly what I wanted, thanks Robert

Comment: is it same with groovy?

Comment: yes it should be the same in groovy except for some minor syntax differences between java an groovy. all the spring libs should be available to use in a groovy project

Comment: `@InjectMock` without an "s" at the end? Which package is this thing from?

Comment: Use org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach annotation instead of @Before for JUnit5

Comment: `@InjectMocks` is mockito. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 14):

I agree with the comment of @skaffman.

Besides your test uses the `MockitoJUnitRunner`, hence it won't look for any Spring stuff, this only purpose is to initialize Mockito mocks. The `ContextConfiguration` is not enough to wire things with spring. Technically with JUnit you can use the following runner if you want spring related stuff : `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Also as you are writing a **Unit Test** you might want to reconsider the use of spring. Using spring wiring in a unit test is wrong. However if you are instead writing an **Integration Test** then why are you using Mockito there, it doesn't make sense (as said by skaffman) !

**EDIT:** Now in your code your a directly setting the `CustomerServiceImpl` in your before block, that doesn't makes sense either. Spring is not involved at all there !

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    customService = new CustomServiceImpl();
    Setter.set(customService, "dataService", dataService);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** If you want to write a **Unit Test** of `CustomerServiceImpl`, then avoid Spring stuff and inject directly the value of the property. Also you could use Mockito to inject the `DataService` mock straigth into the tested instance.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public CustomServiceImplTest{
    @InjectMocks private CustomServiceImpl customServiceImpl;
    @Mock private DataService dataService;

    @Before void inject_url() { customServiceImpl.url = "http://..."; }

    @Test public void customerService_should_delegate_to_dataService() { ... }
}
```

As you might have noticed I'm using a direct access to the `url` field, the field can be package visible. This is a test workaround to actually inject the URL value as Mockito only injects mocks.

Comment: By "reconsider the use of spring" you mean to reconsider the use of Spring configuration files to do the dependency injection for _this test_, right? You are not suggesting that he abandon the use of Spring in his application.

Comment: @jhericks No, I meant to remove Spring related code in the Unit Test. I usually have a hard line on this : I discourage the use of glue code such as Sprin in any **Unit Test**. The **Unit Test**'s purpose is to test in isolation the production code (here `CustomerServiceImpl`). This actually seems to be the intent of the issue's author. If spring is required for some reason, then it begins to be an **Integration Test** which doesn't have the same implications in the test.

Answer (score 1):

You should not mock the thing that you are trying to test. That is pointless since you would not be touching any of the code you are trying to test. Instead get the instance of `CustomerServiceImpl` from the context.

Comment: Don't commit the cardinal sin of Unit Testing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a List of strings reading from Properties file. ReflectionTestUtils class setField method used in @Before block helped me set these values prior to my test execution . It worked perfect even for my dao layer which is depending on Common DaoSupport class.

```
@Before
public void setList() {
    List<String> mockedList = new ArrayList<>();
    mockedSimList.add("CMS");
    mockedSimList.add("SDP");
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(mockedController, "ActualListInController",
            mockedList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little utility class ([gist](https://gist.github.com/0x4a616e/f2cdb576578baf5ccd0d0655d1eec444)) to automatically inject field values into a target class:

```
public class ValueInjectionUtils {
  private static final ExpressionParser EXPRESSION_PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();
  private static final ConversionService CONVERSION_SERVICE = new DefaultConversionService();
  private static final PropertyPlaceholderHelper PROPERTY_PLACEHOLDER_HELPER =
      new PropertyPlaceholderHelper(SystemPropertyUtils.PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX, SystemPropertyUtils.PLACEHOLDER_SUFFIX,
          SystemPropertyUtils.VALUE_SEPARATOR, true);

  public static void injectFieldValues(Object testClassInstance, Properties properties) {
    for (Field field : FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation(testClassInstance.getClass(), Value.class)) {
      String value = field.getAnnotation(Value.class).value();
      if (value != null) {
        try {
          Object resolvedValue = resolveValue(value, properties);
          FieldUtils.writeField(field, testClassInstance, CONVERSION_SERVICE.convert(resolvedValue, field.getType()),
              true);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static Object resolveValue(String value, Properties properties) {
    String replacedPlaceholderString = PROPERTY_PLACEHOLDER_HELPER.replacePlaceholders(value, properties);
    return evaluateSpEL(replacedPlaceholderString, properties);
  }

  private static Object evaluateSpEL(String value, Properties properties) {
    Expression expression = EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression(value, new TemplateParserContext());
    EvaluationContext context =
        SimpleEvaluationContext.forPropertyAccessors(new MapAccessor()).withRootObject(properties).build();
    return expression.getValue(context);
  }
}
```

It uses `org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils` to access all fields annotated with `@Value` and then uses Spring utility classes to resolve all placeholder values. You can also change the type of parameter `properties` to `PlaceholderResolver` in case you like to use your own PlaceholderResolver.
In your test, you can use it to inject a set of values given as a `Map` or `Properties` instance like in the following example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("custom.url", "http://some.url");

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("myProp", props);

ValueInjectionUtils.injectFieldValues(testTarget, properties);
```

This will then try to resolve all `@Value` annotated fields in your `dataService`. I personally prefer this solution over `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(dataService, "field", "value");` as you don't have to rely on hardcoded field names.